# Install new developed features into Sharepoint 2013 production

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, solution-deployment, farm-solution

I've restored a backup from my Intranet production environment into development environment, which I got some errors related to pages layouts. I can ignore this at this time, but my issue is how to install a new features developed in visual studio from Dev to prod without affecting the production environment?

I don't know if this code below works correctly:

```
Update-SPSolution –Identity Myintranetsolution.wsp –LiteralPath "C:\SP\Myintranetsolution.wsp" –GacDeployment
Install-SPFeature -path "Myintranetsolution_Feature3" -Force 
Enable-SPFeature "Myintranetsolution_Feature3" -Url http://myintranetprod -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

If the solutions is **already deployed into the Production** farm and **it contains same set of files** then you can use

```
Update-SPSolution –Identity Myintranetsolution.wsp –LiteralPath "C:\SP\Myintranetsolution.wsp"
```

If it is brand new solution then you have to follow below commands:

```
 Add-SPSolution –LiteralPath "C:\SP\Myintranetsolution.wsp"

Install-SPFeature -path "Myintranetsolution_Feature3" –WebApplication http://myintranetprod -GACDeployment -Force 

Enable-SPFeature "Myintranetsolution_Feature3" -Url http://myintranetprod -Force
```

it will recycle the timer service on the SharePoint servers.